# jqModal cancel alert box open from Iframe but shows in parent window

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqmodal

I have a web page that has an iFrame. I have full access to both parent window and the iFrame page. In the iFrame, I have a jqModal cancel box that is shown when user input some invalid input.
My problem is when the jqModal cancel box is triggered, only content inside of iFrame is tinted, and the message box scrolling position is iFrame's scrolling position.

I am looking for a solution that when jqModal cancel box is triggered, the whole parent window is tinted and the message box's scrolling position is using parent window's scrolling position.

Thank you all.

Comment: Some additional information, like some sample code, would be helpful to solve your problem.  You mention tinting, for example, but the reader has no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You must put jqmodal in parent page not in child page(loded in iframe) then you will have to call jqmdal from iframe. For Example,
Parent:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myGlobalObject = {};
myGlobalObject.LoadJqModal = function(){
  $("selector").jqModal();      
};
</script>
```

Iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function LoadJqModal()
 {
   parent.myGlobalObject.LoadJqModal();
 }
</script>
```